# Add a new connection string via MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, connection-string

I want to add a new connection string (or replace it if exist with the exact name) using MSbuild target task. I know that MSbuild contains XmlPoke, but the command can modify some node or attribute, but how to add a new one?

Before:

```
<connectionStrings>      
    <add name="myDB" connectionString="myCredentials"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

After:

```
<connectionStrings>      
    <add name="myDB" connectionString="myCredentials"/>
    <add name="myCustomKeyAddedDuringMSBuild" connectionString="key=someCredentials" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But if my target configuration file already contains "myCustomKeyAddedDuringMSBuild" connection string, then do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XDT to transform your config file, then you can use xdt:transform="InsertIfMissing".
eg:

```
<add name="myCustomKeyAddedDuringMSBuild" 
    connectionString="key=someCredentials" xdt:transform="InsertIfMissing" 
    xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```